# filtering a data frame using a list and write output in multiple files

Tags: r, dataframe, output, filtering

I am a new in r and I am trying to achieve this task:

I have a data frame such as this:

```
                  V1       V2    V3   V4         V5       V6
1   Maxillaria_grayi -77.9600 -2.35 gbif 2002-04-12 22:00:00
2   Maxillaria_grayi -77.6800 -5.67 gbif 1998-03-22 23:00:00
3   Maxillaria_grayi -76.8333 -7.00 gbif 1998-03-22 23:00:00
4   Maxillaria_grayi -78.6700 -4.27 gbif 1994-02-16 23:00:00
5   Maxillaria_grayi -78.6100 -3.81 gbif 1988-05-15 22:00:00
6 Maxillaria_grandis -77.5900 -0.09 gbif 1979-10-29 23:00:00
```

but whit much more entries.

On the other hand I have a list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Maxillaria_grayi"

[[2]]
[1] "Maxillaria_grandis"

[[3]]
[1] "Maxillaria_huebschii"

[[4]]
[1] "Maxillaria_dalessandroi"
```

and what I am attempting to is to extract information included in my matrix for every entry of my list, and export it as separate outputs.

I have wrote this piece of code:

```
for (n in 1:144){
  x <-  Maxi.matrix[Maxi.matrix$V1 == Maxi[[n]],]
  print(x)
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    write.table(x[[i]], paste(Maxi[[n]], ".txt", sep = ""), col.names=F, row.names=F)
  }
}
```

The first part if working (I think) as it seems it retrieves for every entry in the list all records in the matrix associated with the list record.

```
print(x)
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
                      V1        V2        V3   V4         V5       V6
1022 Scuticaria_hadwenii -43.23444 -22.41028 gbif 2009-11-17 23:00:00
1023 Scuticaria_hadwenii -41.90000 -13.30000 gbif 1992-01-01 23:00:00
1024 Scuticaria_hadwenii -45.86667 -23.63333 gbif 1983-12-09 23:00:00
                       V1     V2    V3   V4         V5       V6
1025 Scuticaria_salesiana -78.37 -5.25 gbif 1996-08-24 22:00:00
1026 Scuticaria_salesiana -78.61 -3.81 gbif 1985-07-24 22:00:00
1027 Scuticaria_salesiana -78.52 -3.43 gbif 1978-08-17 23:00:00

However, the last part of he script (output file) is not working. The loop save a file for every item in the list (e.g. Maxillariella_sanguinea.txt), but the content of the table is not the desired one: e.g.

"22:00:00"
"22:00:00"
"22:00:00"
"22:00:00"
"22:00:00"
"23:00:00"
"22:00:00"
"23:00:00"
"23:00:00"
"23:00:00"
```

Could please somebody give me a hand with this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You want to do `write.table(x, paste.....`.  Now you are saving one column after the other, where the later columns overwrite the earlier ones (leaving you with the last column that contains the times).

Comment: BTW: here is some help on formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @kasterma is correct. It's not clear if you really want to write each column of each group to a "group-column file", or if you want to output *all* columns (together) of each group to a "group file". For the former, you should change your paste call to something like `paste(Maxi[[n]], "-", names(x)[i], ".txt", sep = "")` to distinguish the file names (and thereby prevent overwriting); if the latter, you should remove the inner for-loop and change the first argument of `write.table()` from `x[[i]]` to `x`, as @kasterma indicated.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies!  Kasterma's solution worked great for me and so the new loop looks like this `for (n in 1:144){ x <- Maxi.matrix[Maxi.matrix$V1 == Maxi[[n]],]
  print(x)
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    write.csv(x, paste(Maxi[[n]], ".txt", sep = ""), col.names=c("species", "long", "lat", 
    "prov", "date", "time"), row.names=T)
  }
}` Thanks! :)